# What is the best way to design the GUI in javafx 2.0?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

In javafx 2.0 it is possible to create the layout by using FXML approach or by using normal java code.
What is the best way with respect to a well designed set of UIs. In my application there is about 100 sub UIs.

Thanks

Comment: Focus on your user's needs first. Worry about technology seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FXML looks more logical for that purpose. By using FXML

- you split business logic from view
- you get option to edit design without recompiling project.
- you get design as structured xml tree which is much easier to edit comparing to potentially randomly ordered java code
- with SceneBuider tool you get an option to use visual editor for your fxml files

Answer (score 3):

Get [JavaFX Scenebuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html) here.

Answer (score 1):

*FXForm2 is a library providing automatic JavaFX 2.0 form generation.*

however FXForm2 is not full WYSIWYG GUI design tool.

http://dooapp.github.io/FXForm2/

Answer (score 1):

Scene builder should be a good starting point to create unique UIs of your application. Considering you have 100s of UIs, I assume that some of their "appearances" should be identical with slightly different functions. You can load the FXML dynamically and assign controller at run time. Which means 1 FXML file can be used with multiple controllers. Which can save you some time while keeping the code dynamic for easier maintenance.

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DBedit.fxml"));
    loader.setController(new DBeditEntityUser());
```

So, to make use of the same FXML with a different controller.

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DBedit.fxml"));
    loader.setController(new DBeditEntityUserLevel());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

fyi,

road map for Java fx http://javafx.com/roadmap/  shows that the scene builder will be released around middle of the year. From the above web page:

"JavaFX Scene Builder is a WYSIWYG GUI design tool for the 
JavaFX platform. It enables designing user interface screens by simply 
dragging and positioning  GUI components from a palette onto a scene.

The tool generates files in FXML format2 that can be used within a project 
in any IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse. The JavaFX Scene Builder can be 
used to create GUI for desktop applications and applets that run in a browser."